# Eclipse editor shows unresolved OpenCV symbols and inclusions but builds fine

Tags: eclipse, cmake

I checked out some C++ program that uses OpenCV. I changed the building process to a CMake generated makefile. The OpenCV includes are not set in the Eclipse project settings but in the CMakeLists.txt as `find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )`.

It builds fine, but the Eclipse editor shows all OpenCV related inclusions and symbols as unresolved which is exceedingly annoying. What to do?
Using Eclipse version 4.10.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Sometimes the eclipse builder is not perfect and shows errors that are not valid. Try two things: 1. Go to project and select clean -> select all projects and click clean that will rebuild everything in eclipse. Still getting errors, maybe a corrupt workspace, create a new one and import your projects.

Comment: No luck, I switched to KDevelop for now which seems to work well with CMake.